# How to add environment variable to my app in google play console

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play, google-play-console

Please I have recently launch an app on google play. I have some recent updates which includes environment variables in the app. How do I add the environment variable in my app when released to google play console? I am sure there must be an answer to this on stackoverflow but it seems my search keywords aren't bringing it up. Instead I am seeing this like putting it on google cloud or sth. I don't know if there's any documentation you can redirect me to or just answer to give me a bit of direction on how and where to search on google.

**Minimal reproducible step**

First create a new react native app

Install the [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv)

Follow the steps in the documentation to add it to your project

Create a .env file in the root of your project
**.env**

```
URL=https://stackoverflow.com
```

You can then read the environment variable as the following
EXAMPLE:

```
import { URL } from '@env'
export default App(){
 return(
   <View>
     <Text>{URL}</Text>
   </View>
 )
}
```

Comment: We do not use environment variables in Android apps in general -- that is not really "a thing" in Android. "I have some recent updates which includes environment variables in the app" -- you might want to edit your question with a [mcve] showing what these updates are and how they are attempting to use environment variables.

Comment: @CommonsWare done. I given a minimal reproducible step

Comment: @CommonsWare Also if android apps don't use environment variables does it mean that it's safe to build and deploy the app to google play store with all your secret codes exposed?

Comment: "I given a minimal reproducible step" -- I do not use React Native, but it feels like those are compile-time environment variables, not runtime ones. "does it mean that it's safe to build and deploy the app to google play store with all your secret codes exposed?" -- that depends entirely on your definition of "safe". If you do not want your "secret codes" put on a phone, do not put them on a phone. For example, have your Web service do the work that involves those "secret codes", and focus on having a secured, authenticated connection to the Web service.

Comment: Hi @NewUser134 , I'm the maintainer of `react-native-dotenv` . Make sure you are including the library in your babel config as it is a babel plugin. Let me know how I can improve the documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later found out what I was doing wrong.

Unfortunately, when building to publish on google play, it doesn't read your .env file or any package whatsoever that helps you get access to the file on development mode.

You have to set it (your environment variables) in your `eas.json` for it to be built into the app during production.